# jQuery mobile Android 2.3 - 3 not working

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    handler = new Handler();
    FILENAME = getString(R.string.fileName);

    if(!fileExistance(FILENAME)){
        //create the file
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String string= "{'teamName':'name','players':[{'name':'mary','gol':'2','foto':'xxx','presence':'0'},{'name':'claudia','gol':'3','foto':'xxx','presence':'0'}]}";
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //parsing dei dati dal file
    String json = readFile();
    team = parseJson(json);

    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyTeam");




    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");

}
```

menu.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/myTheme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" /> 

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-chron.min.js"></script>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <img style="float:left;width:41px;" src="themes/images/ball.png"/>
                <img style="float:right;width:41px;" src="themes/images/ball.png"/>
                <div style="text-align:center"><h1 style="font-size: 1.1em;">Futsal Manager 1.0!</h1></div>

                <div id="navbar" style="display:none" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="refresh" >Substitutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="star" >Gol</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="content">           
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" style="margin: 2em;" id="newGame">New Match</a>
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" style="margin: 2em;" id="ranking">Players gol/presence</a>
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" style="margin: 2em;" id="settings">Settings</a>
                <p id="info"></p>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" style="text-align:center">
                    <p class="pFooter">Developed by</p>
                    <img style="text-align:center" src="themes/images/logo.png" />
                    <p class="pFooter">http://www.michelepierri.it</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this page is correctly loaded but when I click on a button I have this exception:12-01 14:45:57.972: E/AndroidRuntime(11229): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

But it work correctly with Android 4.0 and newest, but from Android 2.3 to 3 the app crash.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when the app crashes?

Comment: I have returned this error: 12-01 14:45:57.972: E/AndroidRuntime(11229): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loadURL(final String in){
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl(in);
        }
    });
}

public void loadPage(String in){
    final String url = HTML_ROOT + in;
    //super.loadUrl(url);
    loadURL(url);
}
```